# Bootstrap image gallery modal next/prev buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using this code for bootstrap modal gallery. I need to add next/previous buttons. I try to add buttons but because this is just one modal, i cannot switch between them. Any ideas?
http://www.bootply.com/KBspXYVjaX

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Image` number of the current `Image` in the modal increment/decrement the `Image` number and fetch that image from the list of images with the next & prev buttons:
**jQuery**

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
    $('.modal-body').empty();
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    $('.modal-title').html(title);
    $($(this).parents('div').html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});

$('#next-btn').click(function() {
    var link = $('.modal-body a');
    var number = parseInt(link.attr('title').match(/\S+$/));
    number++;
    if(number === 13) {
        number = 1;
    }
    $('.modal-body').html($('#img-container').find('a[title="Image ' + number + '"]').parent('div').html());
    $('.modal-title').text('Image ' + number);
});

$('#prev-btn').click(function() {
    var link = $('.modal-body a');
    var number = parseInt(link.attr('title').match(/\S+$/));
    number--;
    if(number === 0) {
        number = 12;
    }
    $('.modal-body').html($('#img-container').find('a[title="Image ' + number + '"]').parent('div').html());
    $('.modal-title').text('Image ' + number);
});
```

**Next & Prev Markup**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="prev-btn" class="btn btn-warning">Prev</button>
    <button id="next-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

**Bootply**
http://www.bootply.com/71H5HWFEWP

*I modified your original markup for the images because it jumped from Image 6 to Image 8, so make sure the sequence increments by one.*